# Recover disk space used by Windows installer

Tags: windows-8, disk-space, disk-cleanup

Updating to Windows 8 Pro on my PC consumed an additional 20 Gb or so and I'd like them back. How do I recover the space used by the installer / updater?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Disk Cleanup](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/delete-files-disk-cleanup) with the Clean up system files option.

Comment: Awesome! looks like exactly what I need.

Comment: Does that get rid of Windows.old?

Comment: @Akash That is what is meant by 'Previous Windows installations' This is the recommended method as it avoids problems with permissions which arise if you try to delete it in Explorer.

Answer (score 1):

You should find a Windows.old folder in your C drive

Copy any stuff you need and delete it

Comment: Yes, I do have a Windows.old but it is only about 7 Gb; I also wonder if its "safe" to just delete the entire directory.

Comment: Yes, it is safe, except that you will obviously lose the data in there. Windows does not need that data. You might

Comment: And I would use something like Windirstat to see exactly where the extra disk space is being used

Comment: WinDirStat miscounts hard links so you will have no idea where the disk space goes.

Comment: @Joey are hardlinks actually used by Windows if the user hasnt explicitly made them somewhere?

Comment: I can't take any chances with this particular PC since its used for work, I hope there's a stupid-simple tool I can use specific to this task.

Comment: Akash, yes. The whole WinSxS directory is made up of hardlinks, so you often count all files in there twice, for example.